# ember-data: Inheritance in Parent-Child resources

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Let's say this is my router setup -

router.js :

```
App.Router.map(function(){
     this.resource('photos', function(){
        this.resource('photo', {path: '/:photo_id'}, function(){
            //this.route('edit');
        });
     });
    });
```

photo.js:

```
App.Photo = DS.Model.extend({
 path: DS.attr('string'),
 resolution: DS.attr('string'),
 author: DS.belongsTo('user'),
 dateTaken: DS.attr('date'),
 aperture: DS.attr('string'),
 focalLength: DS.attr('string'),
            .
            .
            .
 exposure: DS.attr('string')

});
```

photosRoute.js:

```
App.PhotosRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return this.store.find('photo');
    }
});
```

photos.hbs:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        {{#each photo in controller}}
            <div class="col-md-4">
                {{#link-to 'photo' photo}}{{photo.path}}{{/link-to}} <br />
                By: {{photo.author}} <br />

            </div>
        {{/each}}
    </div>
</div>

{{outlet}}
```

As seen above, I am only using {{photo.path}} and {{photo.author}} in the photos.hbs template to show the list of all photos. However, in this setup a call to /#/photos would fetch all the bunch of fields for every photo from my django REST server - which I am not interested. Is there a way to fetch just a few fields from the photo model for /#/photos and the complete photo model only when I click on individual photo i.e. /#/photos/photo_id

I have a tried a couple of things:

1. Created a new child resource called 'photoDetail' that extends the original 'photo'. Ideally this should replace the singular 'photo'.
2. From what I gather {async: true} property holds only for async fetching btween models that have relationships setup between them - but not for individual fields in the photo model like: 'exposure', 'focalLength'.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no partially loaded models in Ember-Data. (In fact, I don't think any of the big Ember-Data alternatives have that feature). For the most part your models should be small enough where loading all of the records won't really matter. By the time you enable GZIP, you probably won't even notice a difference. If you have a special use case where bandwidth is extremely limited, you'll probably just want to write your own persistence library. (You could probably also modify Ember-Data or abuse some of its features to accomplish the same task, but I'd recommend against it.)

Comment: Thank You for the reply @GJK. Okay, so from you suggest - I need to have my models small enough. So would the following work: Have 'photos' and 'photoDetails' as 2 separate parallel/sibling resources with a one-to-one relationship between them -

Comment: Also a quick question: if the 'photo' and 'photoDetail' models have one-to-one relationship between them, would they be inherently having the same id? If not how to connect the 2 models with the ids?

Comment: Yes, having two separate models would work, as long as they were somehow linked (like with a one-to-one relationship). Also, I think Ember-Data allows the IDs to be the same as long as they're of a different type (I think).

Comment: Okay. This sure clears some air. I will go back and implement these changes - I need to do some wholesale changes in my REST API too. I would come back and accept the answer when I am done. Thanks a lot!